# How to index rows in pandas dataframe using pd.eval()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

if we can run the following with pandas dataframe:

```
pd.eval('df.A + df.B')
```

Here we are referencing the columns `A` and `B` in the dataframe `df`. How can we perform indexing on rows given the index of the row. Consequently, I have a list of indexes, and I would like to return the specific rows. I tried using:

```
pd.eval('df.loc[list_of_indexes]')
```

but that failed

Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: why do you need pd.eval if you already have the list of indices? Can you create a small example with output expected?

Comment: Okay so I am comparing indexing speed between dataframes and dictionaries. I want to know which one is faster because I have a huge amount of data > 100GB

Comment: if `list_of_indexes` is a variable before, I think you need `@` before like `'df.loc[@list_of_indexes]'` in `pd.eval`, see [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#local-variables)